# "Bad signature" when using Python to verify signature

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, pyopenssl

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
```

When I verify:

```
crypto.verify(pubkey,  binascii.unhexlify(signature), data.encode('GBK'), 
    'sha1')
```

It raises this error:

```
Error: [('rsa routines', 'INT_RSA_VERIFY', 'bad signature')]
```

I don't know why it's a bad signature?

> signature  = '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'

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Facing the exact same error and unable to resolve.